# oracle dynamic pivot error: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table whose data is obtained according to the desired output with pivot. But I want to create the number of columns dynamically.

**my table** :

```
create table myTable(ROW_NAME varchar(10),COLUMN_NAME varchar(10),COLUMN_NAME_VALUE varchar(10));
```

**table data** :

```
insert into myTable (ROW_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_NAME_VALUE)
select 'ROW1','COL1','R1C1' from dual
union all select 'ROW1','COL2','R1C2' from dual
union all select 'ROW1','COL3','R1C3' from dual
union all select 'ROW2','COL1','R2C1' from dual
union all select 'ROW2','COL2','R2C2' from dual
union all select 'ROW2','COL3','R2C3' from dual
union all select 'ROW3','COL1','R3C1' from dual
union all select 'ROW3','COL2','R3C3' from dual
union all select 'ROW3','COL3','R3C3' from dual
```

**my query** :

```
select * from myTable
  pivot (
    max (COLUMN_NAME_VALUE)
    for COLUMN_NAME
    in (
       'COL1' as COL1,'COL2' as COL2,'COL3' as COL3
    )
  )
ORDER BY ROW_NAME;
```

The above query works but I want to get the columns dynamically.

**my dynamic query** :

```
DECLARE
    mycols VARCHAR2(1000);
   sqlCommand varchar2(1000);
   TYPE PivotCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
   pivot_cv   PivotCurTyp;
   piv_rec  mytable%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    select (select LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ',') from myTable group by ROW_NAME FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY) into mycols from dual;
    select Concat('select * from myTable pivot ( max (COLUMN_NAME_VALUE) for COLUMN_NAME in (',Concat(mycols,')) ORDER BY ROW_NAME;')) into sqlCommand from dual;
    
 
    OPEN pivot_cv FOR sqlCommand;
    LOOP
     FETCH pivot_cv INTO piv_rec;
     EXIT WHEN pivot_cv%NOTFOUND;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ROW_NAME: ' || piv_rec.ROW_NAME || ' COL1: ' ||
         piv_rec.COLUMN_NAME_VALUE || 'COL2: ' || piv_rec.COLUMN_NAME_VALUE || 'COL3: ' || piv_rec.COLUMN_NAME_VALUE);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE pivot_cv;

END;
/
```

**Note** : *The equivalent of the above query can be generated on SQL Server and I have created it.*

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ed7ca91955cb1eeb683cab7139f263bb)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 problems in your script:

- semicolon-terminated dynamic query (that's the cause of "SQL command not properly ended")
- identifiers in `in` clause instead of string literals (you can use `'foo'` or `'foo' as foo` but not `foo` alone)
- improper `piv_rec` type - use table format after pivot, not before pivot

Summary:

```sql
DECLARE
   mycols VARCHAR2(1000);
   sqlCommand varchar2(1000);
   TYPE PivotCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;
   pivot_cv   PivotCurTyp;
   type pivotted is record (row_name myTable.row_name%type, col1 myTable.column_name_value%type, col2 myTable.column_name_value%type, col3 myTable.column_name_value%type);
   piv_rec  pivotted;
BEGIN
    select (select LISTAGG('''' || COLUMN_NAME || '''', ',') from myTable group by ROW_NAME FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY) into mycols from dual;
    select Concat('select * from myTable pivot ( max (COLUMN_NAME_VALUE) for COLUMN_NAME in (',Concat(mycols,')) ORDER BY ROW_NAME')) into sqlCommand from dual;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sqlCommand);
   OPEN pivot_cv FOR sqlCommand;
   LOOP
     FETCH pivot_cv INTO piv_rec;
     EXIT WHEN pivot_cv%NOTFOUND;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ROW_NAME: ' || piv_rec.ROW_NAME || ' COL1: ' ||
         piv_rec.COL1 || ' COL2: ' || piv_rec.COL2 || ' COL3: ' || piv_rec.COL3);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE pivot_cv;
END;
/
```

[updated db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2cf53698d743f842fe1ab1af0ecb86e4)  (BTW composing fiddle was very motivating to help)

Comment: Thank you very much for your good and excellent answer. Just a tip on how I can turn the result into a table.